adding certificate to the trusted list in macOS keychain - commandline vs GUI
I was wondering if there's any difference between adding trusted certificate from commandline : sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot ~/c1.cer
and opening the certificate in the keychain UI an mark it as "always trust".
I've got an application that fail on server certificate validation when I mark the server's published certificates as valid from GUI but passes when I do the same from commandline.

The difference may be the user trusting the certificate and the environment running the application. Does the application run as the same user who trusted the certificate?
In the Command Line Interface (CLI) call sudo is used. This will likely mark the certificate as trusted by the user root; being a special user, this trust may apply system wide.
In the Graphical User Interface (GUI) approach, the trust is only being applied for the current user.
